# How to disable Chrome PDF viewer navigation widgets?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

Chrome recently changed their PDF viewer's navigation widgets. Instead of a subtle rectangle in the lower-right corner, there's now a pair of bubbles and a large bar (screenshot below).

This is no good. Is there any way to keep these widget from appearing when I move my mouse?

[image]

Comment: For the record, my current fix is to zoom in on the lower-left corner by sliding my fingers apart (on OSX).

Comment: Chrome will only do this if it receives a direct link to the pdf file, rather than the pdf being embedded. Maybe you can use plug-ins like [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the issue, just append `#toolbar=0` to your file path.

Documentation Reference for my Answer (Read this): https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: Brilliant, toolbar gone! Maybe someday they'll let us remove the zoom bubbles, too.

Comment: Thanks @BenGreenman . From your screenshot, it seems you have older version of chrome or pdfViewer. Try Updating it. Zoom bubbles are no more in existence in newer versions. For old versions,  Google chrome devs have not implemented something to hide the zoom bubbles. Checkout the below discussion of them about the PDF open parameters. 
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-bugs/AhiLZBPQnrc