# Reset Chrome PDF viewer side menu

Tags: javascript, html

I use `iframe` to embed PDF in HTML as follows:

```js
<iframe src="URL" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

First time when you open the pdf, the side Menu is closed. However if you open the side menu, it remains open afterward. So if you open another pdf, the side menu remains open by default as follows:

[image]

Is there any way to set the pdf viewer's side menu in `iframe` to **always** closed every time we open a new pdf.

Comment: You might try appending `#toolbar=0` to the PDF URL as in [How to disable Chrome PDF viewer navigation widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34551624/215552)

Comment: I need to keep the toolbar as it is and with all functionalities. My need is just keep the left side menu bar closed, when we open a pdf.

Comment: As far as I know, Chrome's PDF renderer does not support that. You'd have to use something like [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) or [Adobe's PDF Embed API](https://opensource.adobe.com/pdfembed-sdk-docs/index.html) to get something like that.

Answer (score -1):

try this

> `<iframe src="/path/to/document.pdf#toolbar=0"></iframe>`

add paramater to end your src="url#view=Fit"

you can see https://tinytip.co/tips/html-pdf-params/